# Problema na API após fazer deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-web-api

Minha api não está funcionando após o deploy para o servidor, está retornando:

> 404 - File or directory not found.
>
> #### The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Fazendo uns testes descobri o seguinte, está fazendo a chamada assim e não da certo:

http://meuServidor/api/Livro

mas se eu fizer assim da certo:

http://meuServidor/api/api/Livro

Porque da certo quando coloco `api` duas vezes? não consegui fazer isso no código, aplicar `api` duas vezes na rota.

Comment: Você publicou ela no IIS, certo? Por acaso você criou uma aplicação dentro do "Default web site"?

Comment: `StatusCode 404` significa endereço não encontrado, sua chamada não está batendo na API!

Comment: Já verificou se rota em ambiente de produção está igual a de ambiente em desenvolvimento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**O que aconteceu:**

Você criou um **aplicativo** dentro do seu site(provavelmente *Default Web Site*). Com isso é criado uma *alias*(No seu caso **`api`**) e para acessar sua aplicação é necessário que tenha a *alias* na URL(isso ocorre independente de ser uma **`api`** ou um projeto web), exemplo: http://localhost/**alias**/api/rota

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como resolver:**

Você pode publicar sua **`api`** no "site" *Default* ou criar um "site" para a **`api`**, assim sendo não terá mais que passar a *alias*, no exemplo da imagem, criei um novo site(botão direito em **Sites**>Adicionar site)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Possível "problema":**

Ao criar sites, cada um ficará numa porta, desta forma, se por acaso tiver uma aplicação `web` e uma **`api`** publicadas, cada "site" terá uma porta

Comment: Faz sentido, se esta for a resposta deixo o meu +1

Comment: O estranho era que a pouco tempo atras funcionava, enfim, fiz o que você sugeriu e criei no "Sites" e deu certo.